# Assigning a resource for a resource set to a particular agent

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic, agent

Within a clinical model, I have practitioners seeing patients then returning back to their office after being released. I would like the subsequent visits of that patient to be done by the same practitioners that were seized for the first visit. I assume there will have to be code put into either the 'seize' -> Customize resource choice OR 'ResourcePool' -> Customize request choice where I will specify to select the resource that was selected in the previous seize block. How to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You will have each patient with a variable called practitioner of type Practitioner.

In the customize request choice, you will do the following

```
agent.practitioner==null || agent.practitioner.equals(unit)
```

Then on seize unit you will do

```
agent.practitioner=unit;
```

then the patient will use the same practitioner forever

Comment: After creating a variable named practitioner, then inserting provided lines of code into the resource and seize blocks, I am returned an error saying 'Practitioner cannot be resolved or is not a field'

Comment: then you  didn-t add the variable inside the agent... you added it somewhere else

Comment: but actually you error suggests you are messing upperCase and lower case... JAVA cares about the size of the letters

Comment: It wasn't the capitals but the first problem you mentioned. I know get presented with the error in which I cannot make a static reference to the non-static field patient.practitioner

Comment: why patient.practicioner and not agent.practicioner?

Comment: patient is the agent being sourced and pushed through the model. changing it to agent and it gives the error practitioner cannot be resolved or is not a field. i believe it is a problem now with how i set up the variable

Comment: i don't know, this seems completely unrelated to the question you asked...

Comment: Looks like you haven't set your Seize/Service blocks to be accepting agents of type Patient instead of the vanilla Agent (which is why your properties code can't see the `practitioner` variable you added). See the "Agent type" setting in the Advanced properties. (Some blocks stupidly have two Advanced properties sections; you want the last one.)

Comment: @StuartRossiter I have it set to accept Patient. I believe it may be how I am creating the variable itself. Must I add the practitioner variable to the Patient diagram?

Comment: The error I receive now is that Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field Patient.practitioner

Comment: As Felipe says, you have to use `agent` to access the agent flowing through the block in its actions, *not* `Patient` (which is the name of the agent *type*).

Comment: And, yes, the `practitioner` variable should be defined in the Patient agent type. (It is specific to each Patient who their practitioner is, so it would make no sense to define it elsewhere.)

Comment: I am then presented with a Type mismatch: cannot convert from agent to practitioner as well as cannot convert from practitioner to boolean